# How to create user setting drop menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a user setting drop-down menu that has a similar design to facebook and google on the right, but I'm not sure how. In the attached image you can find what I want to accomplish... Any help is highly appreciated

[image]

Comment: See this is not complicated just read about jQuery's `show, hide, click event` and you are good to go.

Comment: have you tried anything yet ??

Comment: It's so much to do from start. Can you please do a search and start your work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess I did it in the same style I wanted

```
enter code here

  <div class="container">




            <div class="wrapper-demo">

                <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-5" tabindex="1">
                    <div id="image">    </div>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i>Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="iconcog"></i>Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i>Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>


    </div>



enter code here

*,
*:after,
*:before {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}



.wrapper-demo {
margin: 60px 0 0 0;
*zoom: 1;
font-weight: 400;
}




 .wrapper-dropdown-5 {
/* Size & position */
position: relative;
width: 100px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 12px 15px;
height: 50px;
/* Styles */
background: #2F3B31;
border-radius: 0px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 }
#image
{ 
width:45px;
height:46px;
border:solid #666;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/kLz97bG.png?1");
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
margin-top:-10px;
margin-left:-8px;
}

 .wrapper-dropdown-5:after { /* Little arrow */
content: "";
width: 0;
height: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
right: 15px;
margin-top: -3px;
border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #9F9F9F transparent;


 }

 .wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown {
/* Size & position */
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
right: 0;

/* Styles */
background: #9F9F9F;
border-radius: 0px;
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
border-top: none;
border-bottom: none;
list-style: none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

/* Hiding */
max-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
   }
.dropdown
{ 
width:200px;
 }

  .wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li {
  padding: 0 10px ;

  }

 .wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li a {

  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e8ea;
  }

 .wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li:last-of-type a {
 border: none;
 }

 .wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li i {
  width:200px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 color: inherit;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }

 /* Hover state */

.wrapper-dropdown-5 .dropdown li:hover a {
color: #FFFFFF;

 }

/* Active state */

.wrapper-dropdown-5.active {
 border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
 background: #949594;
 box-shadow: none;
 border-bottom: none;
 color: white;
  }

 .wrapper-dropdown-5.active:after {
 border-color: #82d1ff transparent;
  }

 .wrapper-dropdown-5.active .dropdown {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  max-height: 400px;
  }
```

js

```
enter code here
        function DropDown(el) {
            this.dd = el;
            this.initEvents();
        }
        DropDown.prototype = {
            initEvents : function() {
                var obj = this;

                obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }); 
            }
        }

        $(function() {

            var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

            $(document).click(function() {
                // all dropdowns
                $('.wrapper-dropdown-5').removeClass('active');
            });

        });
```

working example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dajin007/ML5Z9/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link :

http://www.9lessons.info/2012/06/simple-drop-down-menu-with-jquery-and.html

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function()
{

$(".account").click(function()
{
var X=$(this).attr('id');
if(X==1)
{
$(".submenu").hide();
$(this).attr('id', '0'); 
}
else
{
$(".submenu").show();
$(this).attr('id', '1');
}

});

//Mouse click on sub menu
$(".submenu").mouseup(function()
{
return false
});

//Mouse click on my account link
$(".account").mouseup(function()
{
return false
});


//Document Click
$(document).mouseup(function()
{
$(".submenu").hide();
$(".account").attr('id', '');
});
});
</script>
```

Html code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<a class="account" >My Account</a>

<div class="submenu">
<ul class="root">
<li ><a href="#Dashboard" >Dashboard</a></li>
<li ><a href="#Profile" >Profile</a></li>
<li ><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
<li ><a href="#feedback">Send Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

CSS

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html { height: 101%; }
body { background: #dde9f0; font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 62.5%; line-height: 1; padding-bottom: 65px; }

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }

blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after { content: ''; content: none; }
strong { font-weight: bold; } 

table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
img { border: 0; max-width: 100%; }

h1 { display: block; font-size: 2.75em; line-height: 2.35em; color: #7291a5; margin-bottom: 12px; font-weight: normal; font-family: 'Oldenburg', 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif; text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff; text-align: center; }

p { font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.35em; color: #343434; margin-bottom: 12px; }

/* page container */
#wrap { display: block; width: 850px; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 35px; }


/* user menu settings */
#dropdown { 
  display: block;
  padding: 13px 16px;
  width: 266px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 4px solid #739cda;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 1.55em;
  color: #656565;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  transition: all 0.15s linear;
}
#dropdown:hover { color: #898989; }

#dropdown.open {
  background: #5a90e0;
  color: #fff;
  border-left-color: #6c6d70;
}

#dropdown ul { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -4px; /* move content -4px because of container left border */
  width: 266px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  display: none;
  border-left: 4px solid #8e9196;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#dropdown ul li { font-size: 0.9em; }

#dropdown ul li a { 
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #447dd3;
  padding: 7px 15px;
}
#dropdown ul li a:hover {
  color: #6fa0e9;
  background: #e7f0f7;
}
```

HTML Marktup

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <title>User Settings Dropdown Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <h1>Stylish User Settings Menu</h1>

    <div id="dropdown" class="ddmenu">
      User Settings
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Friend Requests</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#dropdown").on("hover", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
    $(this).removeClass("open");
    $(this).children("ul").slideUp("fast");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("open");
    $(this).children("ul").slideDown("fast");
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Check JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EhgsF/